# Cladistics question - species of non-terminal nodes

Tags: cladistics

I understand that in a cladogram, the terminal nodes of a full tree are species (or subspecies), while parent nodes represent a branching event in an ancestral population.
It makes sense that in general we won't know what the actual ancestral species was, so the having no species assigned to the parent node makes sense.

But what about a case where we actually knew this? For instance if we directly or indirectly observed some members of a known species rafting to an island and far in the future observed that they had diverged and had no gene flow with the original population.
I'm guessing that we would not assign a new species name to the still existing original population. In that case, what would the cladogram look like in terms of labeling?

I can see that it would make sense to assign subspecies names to both halves of the split as the ancestral population will have also diverged. But what if we had specimens from before the split- how would they be classified?

Answer (score 2):

First: tips are best thought of as individuals, not species. One might have multiple members of the same species even in a phylogeny. Recall that species / subspecies are fundamentally arbitrary groupings, and the higher levels of classification even more so.

It is not very rare to use fossil information to inform phylogenetic modeling, see for example [here](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1319091111?doi=10.1073%2Fpnas.1319091111). This can be helpful for time calibration or character modeling for example.

What I'm not sure that I understand is your questions about subspecies/species naming. It is common for us to apply species names even to long-extinct organisms such as dinosaurs.

If we have sufficient information to decide that an ancestral population constituted a distinct species, why wouldn't we label them as such? Paleontology is very rich in examples of species named in the absence of living "tips".

Comment: I suspect OP was given a "rule" by someone without that "rule" being fully explained.